# sed recognizing only part of HEX sequence

Tags: linux, sed, hex, locale

Stubmled upon strange sed behaviour where only part of HEX sequence is recognized:

There's a string with weird characters that I'm trying to fix and when trying HEX replacement sed finds only first three chars.

`xxd` output of string with problematic characrets:

`6965 7261 f480 8488 6e6f 7761 6e61 2031  iera....nowana 1`

I'd like to replace this sequence `f480 8488` with printable chars, but sed can recognize only first three:

```
sed 's/\xf4\x80\x84/00/g' | xxd
6965 7261 3030 886e 6f77 616e 6120 3136  iera00.nowana 16
```

`f480 84` was properly replaced with `3030`

however

```
sed 's/\xf4\x80\x84\x88/00/g' | xxd
6965 7261 f480 8488 6e6f 7761 6e61 2031  iera....nowana 1
```

doesn't find `f480 8488`

If I break if onto two sed statements `sed 's/\xf4\x80/0/g' | sed 's/\x84\x88/0/g'`everything works fine

I would understand if it was looking for pairs, but why only three not four characters in sequence?

Comment: Are you using a Unicode locale? Does the behavior change if you use `LC_ALL=C sed` ...?

Comment: Yep, LC_ALL=C did the trick. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Following comment @tripleee and confirmed solution form @the.Legend

Setting `LC_ALL=C` is a working fix.
It is well documented [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/87745/what-does-lc-all-c-do).

> It forces applications to use the default language for output:
>
> ```
>  $ LC_ALL=es_ES man 
>  ¿Qué página de manual desea?
>
>  $ LC_ALL=C man 
>  What manual page do you want?
> ```